# Is there a way to use 24-bit or at least 8-bit color in Windows 7 terminal?

Tags: c++, colors, windows-console, color-palette

I have a special need of using the largest color palette possible in Windows 7 console.

Out of the box I have the support for 4-bit RGBI color palette but it's too 
limited for my needs.

I've found that Win 10 supports 24-bit palette but I want it to work on older Windows versions as well (at least Win 7).

Is there a way?

Comment: color is a feature of the terminal. You can't do anything if the terminal doesn't support that feature. And what if the program runs on a terminal without color? They do exist and all Linux apps are still required to check if the TTY supports color to print the proper output

Comment: Right So i'm writing a console dungeon crawler, my goal is to render an image each frame at the time, for now i'm manually setting the characters and their attributes to the buffers. I'm setting characters and attributes with
WinAPI WriteConsoleOutputAttribute and WriteConsoleOutput I'll put my code here after i get to home from work. My problem is that ConsoleOutputAttribute array I can pass there is actually composed of 4-bit RGBI values:
FG_B 0x0001
FG_G 0x0002
FG_R 0x0004
FG_INTENSITY 0x0008
BG_B 0x0010
BG_G 0x0020
BG_R 0x0040
BG_INTENSITY 0x0080

Comment: There will be probably no efforts to enhance the color features of the Windows Console - at a time where this could be achieved easily with a window application. Did you consider to do this (with WinAPI or e.g. Qt)?

Comment: @phuclv
So I'm actually limited to this pallete if i wan't to use it on older CMD terminals.

Comment: @Scheff Yes i did consider it actually but this selfish project's goal is to use terminal only and preferably to be backwards compatible with older windowses.

I have close to none problems with Win10 and my unix terminal, only the black sheep CMD seems to be limited.

Comment: Even older Windowses support window applications. You won't be compatible with DOS? Btw. a Qt application could be compiled for other platforms as well (if done right).

Comment: @Scheff Well youre right but i autisticly want  it to run in console.

Comment: Fake additional color intensities by dithering? ░▒▓█ ;-)

Comment: support for 24-bit color requires a complete overhaul of Windows conhost. If you want that on older Windows you have to use a different terminal. Note that cmd is **not** a terminal. It's a shell just like PowerShell or bash and has to be connected to some terminal (which is conhost.exe on Windows by default) to run

Comment: The source for conhost is available on GitHub, if you want to give it a go :D And that does have the 24 bits color support from Windows 10. But an unmodified conhost from Windows 7 will have 4 bits color.

Comment: 4-bit RGBI color palette is the largest color palette possible in Windows 7 console which shipped with Windows 7.